# Fragment is not replacing properly after adding it to backstack

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have 5 fragments in my activity. 
Fragment A is default one.

and there are sliding menu to switch other 4 fragments in all the fragments.
So I want to add Fragment A only to the backstack.. so 
when calling fragment B/C/D/E from A, A will be added to the backstack.

now from say Fragment B, i am selecting fragment C from menu drawer. without adding it to the backstack. now on pressing back button I can see my default fragment which is correct. but again when I try to change any fragment B/C/D/E from A, fragment A is still visible.

fA->add to backstack->fB->fC->Back button->fA->add to backstack...->fB... but fragment A is still visible here.
any solution for this?

Here is my code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.flContainer, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    if (isAdd) {

        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    transaction.commit();
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Need to apply background color to every parent layout of your different fragment class.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Are you suggesting to overdraw the app? That's a performance issue.. Don't ever do that.

Comment: I am not telling to him draw the app. Just set a background color !!

Comment: If you set a background color you will overdraw the app. I don't think you know what overdraw on android is. Check my blog about that: http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.pt/2015/03/overdraw-in-fragments.html

Comment: still issue. after setting background color to each fragment layout.

Comment: Then you need to add your fragments to Stack arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
```